# Cant Upload image mikrotik-chr on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I start make image mikrotik-chr from my bucket but always error. I dontt know how to fix it

```html
[inflate.import-virtual-disk]: 2021-08-16T05:39:39Z CreateInstances: Creating instance "inst-importer-inflate-6t2qt".
[inflate]: 2021-08-16T05:39:46Z Error running workflow: step "import-virtual-disk" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-08-15T22:39:46.802-07:00 Error:0xc00007b770 HttpErrorMessage:SERVICE UNAVAILABLE HttpErrorStatusCode:503 Id:1873370325760361715 InsertTime:2021-08-15T22:39:40.692-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-1629092379433-5c9a6a095186f-620afe4b-ba26ba50 OperationGroupId: OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a/operations/operation-1629092379433-5c9a6a095186f-620afe4b-ba26ba50 StartTime:2021-08-15T22:39:40.692-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:6947401086746772724 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a/instances/inst-importer-inflate-6t2qt User:606260965808@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Mon, 16 Aug 2021 05:39:46 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}: 
Code: ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
Message: The zone 'projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.
[inflate]: 2021-08-16T05:39:46Z Workflow "inflate" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[inflate]: 2021-08-16T05:39:48Z Workflow "inflate" finished cleanup.
[import-image]: 2021-08-16T05:39:48Z Finished creating Google Compute Engine disk
[import-image]: 2021-08-16T05:39:49Z step "import-virtual-disk" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-08-15T22:39:46.802-07:00 Error:0xc00007b770 HttpErrorMessage:SERVICE UNAVAILABLE HttpErrorStatusCode:503 Id:1873370325760361715 InsertTime:2021-08-15T22:39:40.692-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-1629092379433-5c9a6a095186f-620afe4b-ba26ba50 OperationGroupId: OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a/operations/operation-1629092379433-5c9a6a095186f-620afe4b-ba26ba50 StartTime:2021-08-15T22:39:40.692-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:6947401086746772724 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a/instances/inst-importer-inflate-6t2qt User:606260965808@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Mon, 16 Aug 2021 05:39:46 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}:  Code: ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED; Message: The zone 'projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if you have enough CPUs and other resources quota in 'projects/circular-jet-322614/zones/asia-southeast2-a'. Resource requirement can be found by looking at the deployment specs of the workload.